# replica between dc failed

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, replication

I have 2 dc windows 2003: one is the master and it is called dc, the other is called fs and it is not synchronized with the master.
On the fs server I stopped the service netlogon because I have had problems with the user's logon. The ad db is too old.
On fs there are some events with the following ID: [13508 (replica file)](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-13508-source-FRS-eventno-6585-phase-1.htm), [4000 (dns)](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=4000&source=dns), [2089 (ntds replication, not enough reputation to post the link)

---

EVENT 2089
This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the following number of days.
Directory partition:

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com
"Backup latency interval" (days):

30

It is recommended that you take a backup as often as possible to recover from accidental loss of data. However if you haven`t taken a backup since at least the "backup latency interval" number of days this message will be logged every day until a backup is taken. You can take a backup of any replica that holds this partition.

By default the "Backup latency interval" is set to half the "Tombstone Lifetime Interval". If you want to change the default "Backup latency interval" you could do so by adding the following registry key.
"Backup latency interval" (days) registry key:
System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters\Backup Latency Threshold (days).

---

Are there some cmd to force a resync from dc to fs ?

and what's the problem ? why the replica is stopped ?

thank you.

Comment: Run DCPROMO on FS to demote it. Run DCPROMO on FS to promote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can force AD replication between domain controllers applying following procedure from TechNet [Force Replication Between Domain Controllers](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc816926%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Nevertheless I would like to ask you what do you mean when you say "*... called fs and it is not synchronized with the master*" If you have an Active Directory with 2 domain controllers both of them must be always synced, and if that's not the case you have a problem.

I encourge you to review this article in order to perform some troubleshooting and keep your DC's always as healthy as you can: [Diagnosing and Troubleshooting Active Directory Problems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961826.aspx)

Comment: The server named "fs" is desynchronized to the server named "dc". The server dc is the updated active directory domain controller.

Comment: @Luigi, but is that server ("fs") actually a domain controller?. I'm sorry but I do not understand the term "desynchronized" if we are talking about AD, since if that is the situation, it is far from being a healthy situation for AD. If you are referring to another service, like DFS or something like this then it would be a different situation. Nevertheless it would be good if you could follow procedure I posted in my aswer or run the DCDiag /alltest in both domain controllers.

Comment: I am sorry, my english is very creative :-p - well the dc and fs are both domain controller, but the dc is the updated one. The fs is a domain controller with an old active directory db so that I switched off the netlogon service. If I start netlogon on fs I have many problems with domain users logon. Because the db is very old and the passwords does not match or miss some groups/users. I think the problem is 8-9 months old. On the dc server the AD db is updated and works well.

Comment: @Luigi it was not a problem about the word itself ;) it was about the concept. Nevertheless you are right when you say that the problem is that the DB is too old. You definetelly should read my second link and also run the "DCDiag /alltest" command. I also think that this link could also be useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824449. Hope this helps!